# How to read and set cookies cross domain?

Tags: redirect, cookies, cors, embed, setcookie

I have 2 websites, which are hosted on different doamins, first is on `domain1.com` and second is on `domain2.com`.
Now, I want to access `domain2.com` from `domain1.com`. I can easily achieve this by embedding `domain2.com` on `domain1.com/domain2` using iframes.

But there are 2 problems I am facing -
First, I am not able to read cookies of `domain2.com` on `domain1.com`. I know that this is by design, however, for some reason I cannot modify the `domain2.com` website's source code to include SameSite and Secure attribute.
Now, the request goes through a proxy layer. So, I want to know if a cookie's attributes can be modified at the proxy layer? Or is there any other way to modify cookie attributes before the cookie is set on the browser.

Second, There are cookies on `domain1.com` which needs to be passed to `domain2.com`. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance!